# Pagination-URI in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-4

I began writing a webapp in Codigniter 4 and currently, i'm stuck with the pagination.

I created a controller, a model an a view to retrieve database entries für usergroups and used CI's built-in pagination-library.

**UsergroupsModel:**

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class UsergroupsModel extends Model{

    protected $table = 'roles';
    protected $allowedFields = [];
    protected $beforeInsert = ['beforeInsert'];
    protected $beforeUpdate = ['beforeUpdate'];
    

    public function getGroups(){
        $db = \Config\Database::connect();

        $builder = $db->table('roles');
        $query   = $builder->get();

        $results = $query->getResultArray();
        return $results;
    }

}
```

**Controller (Usergroups):**

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Models\UsergroupsModel;

class Usergroups extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        //Helper laden
        helper(['form','template','userrights']);
        $data = [];
        $data['template'] = get_template();
        $data['info'] = [
            "active" => "menu_dash",
            "title" => "Dashboard",
            "icon" => "fab fa-fort-awesome fa-lg",
                        "sub" => "Frontend",
        ];
        
        //Check Permissions
        $data['userrights'] = get_userrights(session()->get('id'));
        if($data['userrights'][1] == 1)
        {
            foreach($data['userrights'] as $key => $value){
            $data['userrights'][$key] =  '1';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $data['userrights'] = $data['userrights'];
        }

        $model = new UsergroupsModel;
        $model->getGroups();
        $pager = \Config\Services::pager();

        $data['usergroups'] = $model->paginate(5); 
        $data['pager'] = $model->pager;

        //Create Views
        echo view($data['template'].'/templates/header', $data);
        echo view($data['template'].'/backend/navigation');
        echo view($data['template'].'/templates/sidebar');
        echo view($data['template'].'/backend/usergroups');
        echo view($data['template'].'/templates/footer');    
    }

       
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

In the view, i got my pagination by using

```
<?= $pager->links() ?>
```

The default pagination works fine, but i get  an URI like https://DOMAIN.DE/usergroups?page=2

In the official Codeigniter 4 docs for the pagination, you can find the following:

> Specifying the URI Segment for Page
> It is also possible to use a URI segment for the page number, instead of the page query parameter. >Simply specify the segment number to use as the fourth argument. URIs generated by the pager would then >look like [https://domain.tld/model/[pageNumber]](https://domain.tld/model/%5BpageNumber%5D) instead of [https://domain.tld/model?page=[pageNumber].](https://domain.tld/model?page=%5BpageNumber%5D.):

> ::

> $users = $userModel->paginate(10, ‘group1’, null, 3);
> Please note: $segment value cannot be greater than the number of URI segments plus 1.

So in my controller i changed

`$data['usergroups'] = $model->paginate(5);`

to

`$data['usergroups'] = $model->paginate(5,'test',0,2);`

and in the view i added 'test' as a parameter.

`<?= $pager->links('test') ?>`

In the Routes i added

`$routes->get('usergroups/(:num)', 'Usergroups::index/$1');`

and in the Controller i changed the index-function to

`public function index($segment = null)`

The URIs generated from the pagination now look like this:

https://DOMAIN.DE/usergroups/2

but it does not change anything in the entries and the pagination itself alway sticks to page 1.

I think, i can not use CI's built in library when switching to segment-URIs and thus i need to create a manual pagination.

Can somebody help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I currently had the same problem using segments in my pagination.

After much research I discovered that when you use segments associated with a group name in your case "test" you must assign the segment to the variable $ pager

```
$pager->setSegment(2, 'nameOfGroup');
```

You only need to change the first parameter with the segment number that you are using and the second with the name of the group that you are assigning.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's a bug in Version 4.0.3. so it can't work out of the box. But i found a way to solve it:

The index-function needs to look like this:

`public function index($page = 1)`

and

within the Controller, the $data['usergroups'] need to look like this:

`$data['usergroups'] = $model->paginate(5, 'test', $page, 2);`

with 2 being the segment of the page-number in the URI.

Works like a charm.